# Select2 v3.5 opens the select when swiping/scrolling using a mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

So if you access this page using a mobile device or browserstack mobile emulator

http://select2.github.io/select2/

And try to scroll down the page with the pointer (finger) pointed to the select2 box and you start swiping from the select2 box, you will see that it opens the select2 box. When it was swiping, not tapping.

Here I setup a basic [codepen example](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/VLqqqy)

While if you try to do the same on the v4 Select2, it will not open.

The issue that I can't migrate to v4.0 and forced to use this old version.

Is there any way I can prevent opening the select2 boxes when swiping (not tapping) them using a mobile device?

I also looked thru [this commit](https://github.com/select2/select2/commit/0244d7a188efde8856af542c459d282f1e510fb3?diff=split) and tried to replace the source code but it didn't `work`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Since I haven't found a working fixie for this issue, I'll post how I decided to work around this.

```
$(document).on("mousedown touchstart", ".select2-container", function(e) {
    $('select').select2('close');
});
$(document).on("mousedown touchend", ".select2-container", function(e) {
    $('select').select2('close');
});
```

Surely not that beautiful and rational work around, but works as intended.

Comment: For me, it opens and closes. Keeps the keyboard up as well!!

Answer (score 1):

Select2 Version: 3.5.1

Remove "touchstart" from your code.

```
selection.on("mousedown", "abbr", this.bind(function (e) {
    if (!this.isInterfaceEnabled()) return;
    this.clear();
    killEventImmediately(e);
    this.close();
    this.selection.focus();
}));

selection.on("mousedown", this.bind(function (e) {
    // Prevent IE from generating a click event on the body
    reinsertElement(selection);

    if (!this.container.hasClass("select2-container-active")) {
        this.opts.element.trigger($.Event("select2-focus"));
    }

    if (this.opened()) {
        this.close();
    } else if (this.isInterfaceEnabled()) {
        this.open();
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    killEvent(e);
}));
```

Comment: This should be the marked answer.  I wish I had found this sooner.  I've been spending hours trying to implement select2 4.x only to deal with tons of baggage and it being super slow/laggy when initializing large selects.  All to get it to be mobile friendly.

Removing "touchstart" from 2 places in select2.js got me what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer uses the `mousedown` event which makes the select2 close for normal non touch(mouse) events when we try to open.Also added the `css("pointer-events", "none")` so that the element is scrollable.

Note:

1. there is still the small blip where the select2 opens and closes.
2. select2 version - 3.5.1
3. mousedown has comaptibility issues in IE and Safari

```js
$('.select2-container').on("touchmove", function(e) {
  $(this).css("pointer-events", "none");
  $('select').select2("close");
})

$('.select2-container').on("touchstart", function(e) {
  $(this).css("pointer-events", "auto");
});
```